# ajax com jquery - formato dos dados

Tags: jquery, ajax

Uma dúvida. Neste exemplo:

Esse é apenas um teste onde a página api-clientes-editar.php recebe os dados, salva e retorna o status.

```
var dados = $("#editarClientes").serialize();
dados += "&id="+meuID;

console.log(dados);

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "../api/api-clientes-editar.php",
  data: dados,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(retorno,status){

    console.log(retorno);
    console.log(status);
  },

  error: function(retorno,status){
    console.log(retorno); 
    console.log(status);
  }

});
```

Quando os dados são serializados, vendo o console.log, usando "serialize" ficam no formato:

```
campo1=dado1&campo2=dado2&campo3=dado3
```

Agora, se usarmos "serializeArray" os dados ficam no formato:

```
campo1 : dado1, campo2: dado2, campo3: dado3
```

É sabido que podemos passar na mão também, sem usar o serialize. Mas assim facilita :)

Pergunta: Quando seria útil usar um formato ou outro?

Outra coisa. Precisei adicionar o ID na string "dados". Por isso usei o serialize. Mas se fosse no formato serializeArray, como faria para adicionar essa informação?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`serializeArray` cria uma matriz (*array*) (não uma "matriz json" - não existe tal coisa); Você pode testar isso sozinho com o `console.log($("#myform").serializeArray())`. Por outro lado, `serialize` cria uma *string* de consulta que faz parte de uma solicitação *HTTP*. Ambas as representações são equivalentes no sentido de que usando código apropriado você pode converter um para o outro sem qualquer ambiguidade.

A razão para ambas as versões estarem disponíveis é que *serializar* é mais conveniente quando você quer apenas fazer uma requisição *HTTP* (apenas coloque o resultado na string de consulta) enquanto `serializeArray` é mais conveniente se você quiser processar os resultados você mesmo.

Os métodos *AJAX* do *jQuery* não se importam se você der a eles um ou outro porque eles detectam o tipo do parâmetro e o convertem em uma *string* de consulta se já não for uma, de forma que pelo ponto que a requisição é feita os observadores de fora não podem dizer o que foi o formato original dos parâmetros.

> Fonte (tradução livre): [SOen - What's the difference between .serialize() and .serializeArray()?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10430571/5988245)

**Complementando**:

```
dados = 'campo1=dado1&campo2=dado2&campo3=dado3'; // String

dados = {campo1 : dado1, campo2: dado2, campo3: dado3} // Array
```

> Precisei adicionar o ID na string "dados".

Como *string* (`serialize()`): `dados = dados+'&id=1234';`

Como *array* (`serializeArray()`): `dados['id'] = 1234;`

Comment: Eu já tinha visto este post original. Diz que é útil quando eu quiser processar os resultados eu mesmo. Só que não entendi. Como é um exemplo de "processar os resultados"?